# Enviar un body que sea json con httpclient

Tags: c#, rest

estoy intentando hacer un post pero necesito que tenga un body

Este body tiene que tener esta forma:

```
"{\"UserUid\":\"1234\"}"
```

He intentado crear el content asi:

```
var jsonIden = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userUid); 
var content = new StringContent(jsonIden, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Pero no me forma bien el mensaje.

Comment: La variable `userUid` que contiene?

Comment: ¿Que mensaje te forma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te fijas el cuerpo tiene llaves por lo que es un objeto, y tu solo le estas pasando una simple variable.

Basare mi respuesta en que **`userUid`** es una cadena, ya que en tú ejemplo lo defines así.
Como coloque al principio, lo que debes serializar es un objeto y no una variable simple.

Te dejo un ejemplo serializando con un objeto tipo anónimo:

```
string userUid = "1234";
var jsonIden = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { UserUid = userUid });
var content = new StringContent(jsonIden, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Para crear el objeto tipo anónimo, use el operador ***new*** y dentro de las llaves se colocan las propiedades del objecto.

Si no quieres utilizar tipos anónimos, también puedes crearte una clase con las propiedades necesarias y después la serializas, esta es una forma para no tener tipos anónimos repetidos por todo el código.

> [Tipos anónimos](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types): Los tipos anónimos son una manera cómoda de
>   encapsular un conjunto de propiedades de solo lectura en un único
>   objeto sin tener que definir primero un tipo explícitamente. El
>   compilador genera el nombre del tipo y no está disponible en el nivel
>   de código fuente. El compilador deduce el tipo de cada propiedad.

Answer (score 0):

prueba este codigo y comentas

Declara una clase

```
public class Formatjson
    {
        public string Folio { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
    }
    public class ListJson
    {
        public List<Formatjson> UserUid { get; set; }
    }
```

Dentro del evento del boton o donde lo quieras poner esto

```
 string datos;

        var RootObject = new ListJson();
        RootObject.UserUid = new List<Formatjson>();


                var folio = new Formatjson()
                {
                    Folio = "1234",//aqui le pasas la informacion
                    Nombre = "Prueba formato json"//aqui le pasas la informacion
                };
                RootObject.UserUid.Add(folio);


                datos = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RootObject);
                MessageBox.Show(datos);//solo para ver los datos, lo puedes borrar
```

Si te sirvio puedes marcarla como respuesta.

Comment: Tu idea esta muy bien, pero implica crear un nuevo objeto. La otra repuesta ha sabido ver que el objeto ya estaba creado y con añadir : new { UserUid = userUid } en el parametro lo envia correctamente el json